# Bash script failing to execute NPM scripts for Cypress

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, cypress, sh

I am running into an issue with a bash script I made. For context, I have written NPM scripts to run Cypress tests on the command line. My goal is to have a bash script that runs each of these NPM scripts, and executes Cypress in the command line. Also for reference, my script.sh is located in the project folder.

If I run my NPM scripts manually from my terminal, there's no issue. Cypress works. Here is an example of an NPM script I have:

```
"cypress:window": "./node_modules/.bin/cypress open",
```

The problem is when I put those commands into a bash script. Now, when script.sh runs it executes with code=1 and does not actually run Cypress at all. My script.sh is just:

```
npm run cypress:window
```

Comment: What's your file structure? Where is your script being executed from?

Comment: Also, are you receiving any error message you can provide us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was an issue with my .sh entirely. The solution was to ensure the file had executable rights. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

Most likely the problem is the relative path in the package.json script. When you set up Cypress in the conventional way, they remove the need to reference the exact path in the script instead you can do this

```js
// package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "cypress:window": "cypress open",
    ...
  }
}
```

Please see [How to run commands](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line#How-to-run-commands) for all the options